# CPU > 80% - how can I debug?

Tags: performance, cpu

I am running a laravel application on a Ubuntu 14.04 digital ocean vps and I am using New Relic to monitor the server.

I got an email alert that my CPU usage was above 80%. I logged in to New Relic and now it's showing my CPU usage at 99% for 18 hours now. But when I log into my shell and run 'top' the CPU usage of the processes don't even sum up to 10%.

What could be wrong? Which are other commands I could run to check the real usage and what is using it so much? (Perhaps an infinite loop on the application?)

This is my htop result:

[image]

And this is htop after shift+K

[image]

Any links or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My first question is: What properly written PHP process has a run-duration of 1h24 minutes?

Comment: Maybe Otheus's attitude would make sense if we were in the 90's, but 'Why are you using PHP for that' this is totally not the way to respond to a unix system admin question

Comment: that htop seems to be showing 100% cpu use...

Comment: Malware hides its own processes.  Out of curiosity, do you have a /etc/ld.so.preload file?  If so, is there anything suspicious in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's going on, but my guess is that the individual process's %CPU column isn't telling you what you think it tells you. From top's manpage:

```
  k: %CPU  --  CPU usage
  The task’s share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update,
  expressed as a percentage of total CPU time.
```

Let's say you're refreshing every 4 seconds. The total CPU time it consumed in those 2 seconds is 6% *over those 4 seconds*. But let's say in one of those seconds, it spurted and used 24% of CPU time. I'm not saying this is happening, but it could be.

I am happy with `top` here. I can see CPU usage broken down by CPU and further by `user`, `sys`, `nice`, `idle`, `wait` (on I/O), servicing hardware and software interrupts (hi, si). You can probably get this in `htop` as well. As long as you have 1 CPU that is at least 20% idle, there's little to actually worry about, unless your fan is bothering you. But if you're worried, maybe what's happening is %wait and %hi/%si are very high, in which case no individual process is having a high CPU usage, but rather, the kernel is very very busy for some reason.

Comment: You can get detailed cpu time in `htop` via the setup menu but idle is *never* included in cpu usage stats.  If the cpu was 20% idle that would show up in `htop` even without detailed stats

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I did run TOP command in background and redirect it to a txt file

top > top.txt &

Thank you can see which process waste your CPU

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.  My preference is the program `htop` which isn't generally installed by default but is available for almost all distros.  It gives you the same info as `top` but with a MUCH richer feature set.  It's great for interactively finding the problem process but it's not great for scripting. If you want to incorporate something into a monitoring script the command `ps -eo pid,pcpu,comm` will be your friend.  It prints all of the current processes along with their PID and CPU usage in a fairly easy-to-parse format.

Comment: htop shows the same as top, the sum of all usage is about 9%.
the other command ps... shows everything at 0.0, some at 0.2

Comment: What is the load average on the server (it's shown in the top right corner of `htop`)?

Comment: 1.22, 1.30, 1.31

Comment: and CPU that show on top of htop, shows 100%

Comment: edited the question with more information

Comment: Is `htop` showing kernel processes or just user-land processes?  `Shift+k` will toggel the display of kernel processes.

Comment: edited with htop after shift+k..

Comment: This is a really strange one.  Could you post the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I like dstat :)

Answer (score 0):

> What could be wrong?

The first thing is that you're using Laravel which likes a lot of memory and you only have less than half a gig. You're running it on an out of support operating system - which is bad. And you've not told us about the rest of the stack (webserver, PHP SAPI, PHP version).

Comment: At the time of the posting, the OS was not out of support.

Comment: Missed that  - ta.